# Habilitar campos em Jquery

Tags: jquery

Tenho os seguintes campos:

```
<label class="control-label">KM</label>
<input class="input-small" style="width: 50px !important;" type="text" name="km" value="">

<label class="control-label" style="width: 75px !important;" >Descarga</label>
<input class="input-small" style="width: 50px !important;" type="text" name="descarga" value="" disabled>

<label class="control-label" style="width: 75px !important;" >Pernoite</label>
<input class="input-small" style="width: 50px !important;" type="text" name="pernoite" value="" disabled>

<label class="control-label" style="width: 75px !important;" >Romaneio</label>
<input class="input-small" style="width: 50px !important;" type="text" name="romaneio" value="" disabled>
```

Note que somente o primeiro campo está habilitado.

Preciso que, ao preencher algum dado no campo primeiro, habilite os demais.

Como fazer isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utilize a função `.on()` para definir os eventos desejados, no nosso caso `keyup` (verificar se alguma tecla foi pressionada, quando a tecla sobe) e `change` (verifica se o valor do campo mudou), depois utiliza a função `.prop()` para manipular a propriedade `disabled` dos seus campos

```js
$(function(){
  $("input[name='km']").on("keyup change", function(){
    campos = "input[name='descarga'],input[name='pernoite'],input[name='romaneio']";
    if ($(this).val()) {
      $(campos).prop({disabled:false});
    } else {
      $(campos).prop({disabled:true});
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="control-label">KM</label>
<input class="input-small" style="width: 50px !important;" type="number" name="km" value="">

<label class="control-label" style="width: 75px !important;" >Descarga</label>
<input class="input-small" style="width: 50px !important;" type="text" name="descarga" value="" disabled>

<label class="control-label" style="width: 75px !important;" >Pernoite</label>
<input class="input-small" style="width: 50px !important;" type="text" name="pernoite" value="" disabled>

<label class="control-label" style="width: 75px !important;" >Romaneio</label>
<input class="input-small" style="width: 50px !important;" type="text" name="romaneio" value="" disabled>
```

Comment: Neste caso tem que preencher e clicar fora para habilitar os campos, queria que ao preencher já habilitasse...

Comment: entendi, quando ficar vazio quer que desabilite de novo?

Comment: Isso mesmo! Ficou vazio, desabilita.

Comment: Como eu conseguiria habilitar para preencher somente números nestes campos?

Comment: http://www.maisumpixel.com.br/categoria/jquery/somente-numeros-em-campo-input

Comment: defina o tipo dele para _number_, vou colocar na resposta com um campo do tipo _number_, mas nesse caso também será necessário verificar o `.change()`, poruqe pode-se clicar nas setas de troca de valor

Answer (score 2):

Pode ser feito assim, de uma classe em comum para os `inputs`, no exemplo usei `classeteste`, e pode usar um código parecido com esse:

```js
$(function() { 
 $("#IDDOPRIMEIROINPUT").keyup(function(){
  if($(this).val())
   $(".classeteste").prop('disabled', false);
  else
   $(".classeteste").prop('disabled', true);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="control-label">KM</label>
<input id="IDDOPRIMEIROINPUT" class="input-small" style="width: 50px !important;" type="text" name="km" value="">

<label class="control-label" style="width: 75px !important;" >Descarga</label>
<input class="input-small classeteste" style="width: 50px !important;" type="text" name="descarga" value="" disabled>

<label class="control-label" style="width: 75px !important;" >Pernoite</label>
<input class="input-small classeteste" style="width: 50px !important;" type="text" name="pernoite" value="" disabled>

<label class="control-label" style="width: 75px !important;" >Romaneio</label>
<input class="input-small classeteste" style="width: 50px !important;" type="text" name="romaneio" value="" disabled>
```